# Android bluetooth Printing Runtime Error

Tags: android, android-layout, printing, bluetooth

I have a program that sends data from android mobile phone to mobile printing Bluetoth. I am having trouble with my code. runtime error occurs. I can not analyze it. please help. Thank you very much

This is sample my code:

```
   private static final String TAG = "Test";
    static final private int PrintText_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    static final private int PrintBarcode_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    static final private int LineFeed_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    static final private int SetCharacterSet_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
    static final private int Connect_ID = Menu.FIRST + 5;
    static final private int Disconnect_ID = Menu.FIRST + 6;    
    static final private int GetStatus_ID = Menu.FIRST + 7;
    static final private int GetPowerStatus_ID = Menu.FIRST + 8;
    static final private int Directio_ID = Menu.FIRST + 9;
    static final private int MsrTrack1_ID = Menu.FIRST + 10;
    static final private int MsrTrack2_ID = Menu.FIRST + 11;
    static final private int MsrTrack3_ID = Menu.FIRST + 12;
    static final private int MsrTrack12_ID = Menu.FIRST + 13;
    static final private int MsrTrack23_ID = Menu.FIRST + 14;
    static final private int PrintText1K_ID = Menu.FIRST + 15; 

    private ZQPrinter PrinterService = null;   
    private boolean conn = false;

    private byte dataBar[] ={0x38, 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x35, 0x31, 0x31};    //"JAN13(EAN) 8801115114031"
    private byte dataBar2[] ={0x38, 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x31};
    private byte dataBar3[] = {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37};
    String PrintTextSample="ABCDEFGabcdefg123456!@#$%^\r\n";


    public ZQExample()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON Contructor +++"); 

    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CheckGC("onCreate_Start" );
        Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);        
        registerForContextMenu(t);

        PrinterService = new ZQPrinter();
        CheckGC("onCreate_End" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        CheckGC("onStart_Start" );
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); 
        t.setText("");              
        t.append("AM-3XM EXAMPLE\n\n");          
        t.append("do long press on touchscreen\n");
        Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");
        CheckGC("onStart_End" );
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");
        CheckGC("onResume_End" );
    }    

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
        CheckGC("onPause_End" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
        CheckGC("onStop_End" );
        // defense code for HTC Desire because of reconnect' fail       
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);       
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");  
        super.onDestroy();
        if(PrinterService != null)
        {   
         PrinterService.Disconnect(); 
         PrinterService = null;
        }
        CheckGC("onDestroy_End" );
    }   

    @Override   
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        CheckGC("onCreateContextMenu_Start" );
        if (conn == false) {
            menu.add(0, Connect_ID, 0, "Connect");
        } 
        else {
            menu.add(0, Disconnect_ID, 0,  "Disconnect");
            menu.add(0, PrintText_ID, 0,  "PrintText"); 
            menu.add(0, PrintText1K_ID, 0,  "PrintText1K");
            menu.add(0, PrintBarcode_ID, 0,  "PrintBarcode");
            menu.add(0, LineFeed_ID , 0,  "LineFeed");
            menu.add(0, GetStatus_ID , 0,  "GetStatus");
            menu.add(0, GetPowerStatus_ID, 0,  "GetPowerStatus");
            menu.add(0, Directio_ID, 0,  "Directio");
            menu.add(0, MsrTrack1_ID, 0,  "MsrTrack1");
            menu.add(0, MsrTrack2_ID, 0,  "MsrTrack2");
            menu.add(0, MsrTrack3_ID, 0,  "MsrTrack3");
            menu.add(0, MsrTrack12_ID, 0,  "MsrTrack12");
            menu.add(0, MsrTrack23_ID, 0,  "MsrTrack23");
            menu.add(0, SetCharacterSet_ID, 0,  "SetCharacterSet");
        }
        CheckGC("onCreateContextMenu_End" );
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int returevlaue=ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS;
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);   
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case Connect_ID:
            CheckGC("Connect_Start" );

            t.setText("");
            t.append("Connect...\n");
            int nRet = PrinterService.Connect("00:1F:B7:03:C8:05");
            if ( nRet == 0 ) {
                t.append("Success\n");
                conn = true;
            }
            else {
                Log.e("Test", String.valueOf(nRet));
                t.append("Fail\n\n"); 
                Toast.makeText(ZQExample.this,"check printer & bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                conn = false;               
            }
            t.append("do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            CheckGC("Connect_End" );            
            //////
            return true; 
        case Disconnect_ID:
            CheckGC("Disconnect_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("Disconnect...\n");        
            PrinterService.Disconnect(); 
            PrinterService = null;
            t.append("Success\n\n");            
            t.append("do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            conn = false; 
            CheckGC("Disconnect_End" );
            return true;

        case PrintText_ID:
            CheckGC("PrintText_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("PrintText...\n"); 
            //////
            System.setProperty("file.encoding", "gb2312");
            String str = "²âÊÔ´òÓ¡¼òÌå\r\n";
            PrinterService.PrintText(str, ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT, ZQPrinter.FT_DEFAULT, 0);
            //////
            System.setProperty("file.encoding", "big5");
            String str2 = "œyÔ‡´òÓ¡·±ów\r\n";
            PrinterService.PrintText(str2, ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT, ZQPrinter.FT_DEFAULT, 0);
            //////////
       returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();    
        if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){   
           for(int i=0 ; i<50;i++) 
           {       
               returevlaue=PrinterService.PrintText(PrintTextSample,
                        ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
                        ZQPrinter.FT_DEFAULT, 
                        ZQPrinter.TS_0WIDTH | ZQPrinter.TS_0HEIGHT );
                    CheckGC("PrintText_Loop" );
               if(returevlaue!=ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS)
                {
                    break;
                }

           }
        }

        if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
            returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(5);
        }

        returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
            }


            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");  
            CheckGC("PrintText_End" );
            return true;

        case PrintBarcode_ID :
            CheckGC("PrintBarcode_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("PrintBarcode...\n");  
             returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.PrintBarcode(dataBar ,dataBar.length ,  ZQPrinter.BCS_JAN13, 50, 3,  ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,  ZQPrinter.BC_TEXT_BELOW);
            }
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(1);
            }

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.PrintBarcode(dataBar2,dataBar2.length,  ZQPrinter.BCS_JAN8, 50, 3,  ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,  ZQPrinter.BC_TEXT_BELOW);
            }
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(1);
            }

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.PrintBarcode(dataBar3 ,dataBar3.length ,  ZQPrinter.BCS_Code39, 50, 3,  ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,  ZQPrinter.BC_TEXT_BELOW);
            }
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(1);
            }

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.PrintBarcode(dataBar3, dataBar3.length,  ZQPrinter.BCS_Code128, 50, 3,  ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT,  ZQPrinter.BC_TEXT_BELOW);
            }
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
             returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(1);
            }
            returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){ 
              t.append("Success\n\n");

            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
            }         
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            CheckGC("PrintBarcode_End" );
            return true;      

        case LineFeed_ID :   
            CheckGC("LineFeed_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("LineFeed...\n"); 
            returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();

            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){ 
              returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(5);
            }

            returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
            }

            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");  
            CheckGC("LineFeed_End" );
            return true;            

        case GetStatus_ID:   
            CheckGC("GetStatus_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("GetStatus...\n");             
            returevlaue=PrinterService.GetStatus();
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
            }            
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            CheckGC("GetStatus_End" );
            return true;

        case SetCharacterSet_ID:
            CheckGC("SetCharacterSet_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("SetCharacterSet...\n");           
            returevlaue=PrinterService.SetCharacterSet(0);
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){ //0:USA, 19:Euro
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="Data ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
            }           
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");  
            CheckGC("SetCharacterSet_End" );
            return true;       

        case GetPowerStatus_ID:  
            CheckGC("GetPowerStatus_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("GetPowerStatus...\n");            
            returevlaue=PrinterService.GetPowerStatus();
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
            }else if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.PWR_HIGH){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="BXL_PWR_HIGH ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;

            }else if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.PWR_MIDDLE){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="BXL_PWR_MIDDLE ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;

            }else if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.PWR_LOW){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="BXL_PWR_LOW ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;

            }else if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.PWR_SMALL){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="BXL_PWR_SMAL ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;

            }else if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.PWR_NOT){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="BXL_PWR_NOT ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;

            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
            }           
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");
            CheckGC("GetPowerStatus_End" );
            return true;

        case MsrTrack1_ID:
            CheckGC("MsrTrack1_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("MsrTrack1...\n");  
            byte[] i1 = PrinterService.MsrTrack1();
            char temchar1;
            if(i1!=null){
                PrintOutput("MsrTrack1",i1);
                t.append("Success\n\n");
               //////////////////////////////////// 
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="Data :("+i1.toString()+") ";
                for(int i=0;i<i1.length;i++)
                {
                    temchar1=(char)i1[i];
                    tem_buffer=tem_buffer+" "+temchar1;
                }
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
              ///////////////////////////////////////   
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
            }       
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");   
            i1=null;
            CheckGC("MsrTrack1_End" );
            return true;    

        case MsrTrack2_ID:
            CheckGC("MsrTrack2_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("MsrTrack2...\n");  
            byte[] i2 = PrinterService.MsrTrack2();
            char temchar2;
            if(i2!=null){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
                PrintOutput("MsrTrack2",i2);
            ////////////////////////////////////    
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="Data :("+i2.toString()+") ";
                for(int i=0;i<i2.length;i++)
                {
                     temchar2=(char)i2[i];
                     tem_buffer=tem_buffer+" "+temchar2;
                }
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
            ////////////////////////////////////
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
            }        
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            i2=null;
            CheckGC("MsrTrack1_End" );
            return true;      

        case MsrTrack3_ID: 
            CheckGC("MsrTrack1_End" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("MsrTrack3...\n");  
            byte[] i3 = PrinterService.MsrTrack3();
            char temchar3;
            if(i3!=null){
                 PrintOutput("MsrTrack3",i3);
                 t.append("Success\n\n");
                ////////////////////////////////////
                 String tem_buffer=new String();
                 tem_buffer="Data :("+i3.toString()+") ";
                 for(int i=0;i<i3.length;i++)
                 {
                     temchar3=(char)i3[i];
                     tem_buffer=tem_buffer+" "+temchar3;
                 }
                 t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                 tem_buffer=null;
                ////////////////////////////////////
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
            }        
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            i3=null;
            CheckGC("MsrTrack1_End" );
            return true;
        case MsrTrack12_ID: 
            CheckGC("MsrTrack12_End" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("MsrTrack12...\n");  
            byte[] i4 = PrinterService.MsrTrack12();
            char temchar4;
            if(i4!=null){
                 PrintOutput("MsrTrack12",i4);
                 t.append("Success\n\n");
                ////////////////////////////////////
                 String tem_buffer=new String();
                 tem_buffer="Data :("+i4.toString()+") ";
                 for(int i=0;i<i4.length;i++)
                 {
                     temchar4=(char)i4[i];
                     tem_buffer=tem_buffer+" "+temchar4;
                 }
                 t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                 tem_buffer=null;
                ////////////////////////////////////
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
            }        
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            i4=null;
            CheckGC("MsrTrack12_End" );
            return true;
        case MsrTrack23_ID: 
            CheckGC("MsrTrack23_End" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("MsrTrack23...\n");  
            byte[] i5 = PrinterService.MsrTrack3();
            char temchar5;
            if(i5!=null){
                 PrintOutput("MsrTrack23",i5);
                 t.append("Success\n\n");
                ////////////////////////////////////
                 String tem_buffer=new String();
                 tem_buffer="Data :("+i5.toString()+") ";
                 for(int i=0;i<i5.length;i++)
                 {
                     temchar5=(char)i5[i];
                     tem_buffer=tem_buffer+" "+temchar5;
                 }
                 t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                 tem_buffer=null;
                ////////////////////////////////////
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
            }        
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n"); 
            i5=null;
            CheckGC("MsrTrack23_End" );
            return true;
        case Directio_ID: 
            CheckGC("Directio_Start" );
            t.setText("");          
            t.append("Directio...\n");  
            byte sendApdu[] = {0x10, 0x04, 0x01}; 
            byte[] readData = new byte[1];
            int[] readLength = new int[1];
            readLength[0]=readData.length;
            returevlaue=PrinterService.Directio(sendApdu,sendApdu.length,readData,readLength);
            if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
                t.append("Success\n\n");
             ////////////////////////////////////
             String tem_buffer=new String();
             tem_buffer="DataSize:("+readLength[0]+") ,Date : ";
             for(int i=0;i<readLength[0];i++)
             {
                 tem_buffer=tem_buffer+" "+readData[i];
             }
             t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
             tem_buffer=null;
             ////////////////////////////////////   
            }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
            }           
            t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");
            CheckGC("Directio_End" );
            return true;
        case PrintText1K_ID: 
            CheckGC("PrintText1K_Start" );
             t.setText("");         
             t.append("PrintText1K...\n"); 

             String test=new String();  
             for(int i=0 ;i<120;i++)
             {
                 test+="ABCDEFGabcdefg123456!@#$%^ ";
             }

             returevlaue=PrinterService.PrintText(test, 
                        ZQPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT, 
                        ZQPrinter.FT_DEFAULT, 
                        ZQPrinter.TS_0WIDTH | ZQPrinter.TS_0HEIGHT );


             if(returevlaue==ZQPrinter.AB_SUCCESS){
                returevlaue=PrinterService.LineFeed(5);
                t.append("Success\n\n");
             }else{
                t.append("Fail\n\n");
                String tem_buffer=new String();
                tem_buffer="ERROR ["+returevlaue+"]";
                t.append(tem_buffer.subSequence(0,tem_buffer.getBytes().length));
                tem_buffer=null;
             }

             test=null;
             t.append("\n do long press on touchscreen\n");  
             CheckGC("PrintText1K_End" );
             return true;

        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    void CheckGC(String FunctionName)
    {
        long VmfreeMemory =Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        long VmmaxMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        long VmtotalMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        long Memorypercentage=((VmtotalMemory-VmfreeMemory)*100)/VmtotalMemory; 

        Log.i(TAG,FunctionName+"Before Memorypercentage"+Memorypercentage+"% VmtotalMemory["+VmtotalMemory+"] "+"VmfreeMemory["+VmfreeMemory+"] "+"VmmaxMemory["+VmmaxMemory+"] ");

          //Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
          System.runFinalization();
          System.gc();
          VmfreeMemory =Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
          VmmaxMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
          VmtotalMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
          Memorypercentage=((VmtotalMemory-VmfreeMemory)*100)/VmtotalMemory; 
        Log.i(TAG,FunctionName+"_After Memorypercentage"+Memorypercentage+"% VmtotalMemory["+VmtotalMemory+"] "+"VmfreeMemory["+VmfreeMemory+"] "+"VmmaxMemory["+VmmaxMemory+"] ");
    }
    public void PrintOutput(String FunctionName,byte[] Data)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Data.length;i++)
        {
            Log.i(TAG,FunctionName+"Data["+i+"]="+Data[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "I have trouble with my code" is rather broad. Please be specific about your problems. Also, try to minimize the amount of code you post. It's best if you can provide us with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Good luck!

Comment: sorry, I'm new here. :) Thank you guidance
trouble when I get my code running in the emulator. I can not identify.

Comment: You're welcome. You say it's a runtime error; maybe you could tell us what happens when you run it in the emulator. Maybe it's just a NullPointerException; you should be able to see that in the stack trace of the emulator.

Comment: you may getting the NullPointerException if you are testing it on the emulator

Comment: can you please post your logcat